# NSLocalizedString put specific symbol

Tags: objective-c, xcode, string, nslocalizedstring

I have some trouble with NSLocalized string. Please give me advice.

I create Localizable.strings and need this text:

```
"Main Label" = "Car "BMW"";
```

But it doesn't compile. How can I write this? (I need to use "").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to escape the quotation mark. Try this,

```
"Main Label" = "Car \"BMW\"";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use backslash as prefix:

```
"Main label" = "Car \"BMW\"";
```

More info about strings: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html